# ORACLE - Temporal change in archivelog mode

Tags: oracle

I need to change temporarly (in order to run a proccess) the archiving mode to noarchivelog.
After switching back to archivelog, do I need to open the database with resetlogs option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resetlogs is not required. You can turn Archive Mode on and off at will, just be aware that any log switches that occur during while it is off will mean you will have gaps in logs saved on disk.

This means you may be sacrificing recoverability. After turning Archive Mode back ON I would perform a full backup.

Comment: Yes, I known the implications of changing the archive mode. What I wanted to know was if a need to open the database with resetlogs option. I supposed this isn't necessary, but I wanted to be sure. Thanks!!

Comment: I did a test on a 9i database and it worked out fine. (The transcript is lengthy so I will refrain from posting here). The log sequence just keeps counting up with each Online Redo Log switch. When you turn ARCHIVELOG back on, it will start writing files again with the next log switch, and it will be using the most recent Log Sequence #.

Answer (score 0):

After running in noarchivelog mode, your archive logs are not usable anymore. Therefore you need to reset after opening again. Remember to take a backup before and after the operation.

Comment: It wouldn't cause an "ORA 1139: RESET LOGS option only valid after an incomplete database recovery " error ?

Comment: Sure they are still usable, to do a point in time recovery to the point right before you turned OFF archive logs.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to get away with using NOLOGGING on objects without requiring to restart to set NOARCHIVELOG mode.